# Scraping data with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this line of html:

```
<td title="Druid"><a href="/pvp/druid"><img src="/images/classes/druid.png" class="img-responsive center" alt="Druid"></a></td>
```

Using python and beautiful soup,
I'd like to access the the "Druid" from `<td title="Druid">` to be stored as a variable.

Comment: Hi! We normally ask that people post their first attempt(s) at cracking their problem here on Stack Overflow - if you could add those it'd be super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the title of the td:

```
bs4.BeautifulSoup(data).find("td")["title"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the attributes of a tag treat it just like a dictionary:

```
soup.find('td').get('title')
```

or

```
soup.find('td')['title']
```

**Note:** *`.get('title', 'some default value')` allows you to provide a default value if the key is missing or if omitted is `None`, while `['title']` will raise a KeyError*

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<td title="Druid"><a href="/pvp/druid"><img src="/images/classes/druid.png" class="img-responsive center" alt="Druid"></a></td>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

character = soup.find('td').get('title')

print(character)
```

#### Output

```
Druid
```

Comment: Definitely, if there were more information in the question - for the given example, however, I think it must be sufficient and adapted. Focus is to access the attribute title.